# Djano remot user login via java script

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users, django-login

In my **django application hosted on heroku** (https://ers-heatscreen-app.herokuapp.com) , i would like to authenticate users from an existing customer login on a productive homepage which is solved with java script.

So when they login at https://shop.ers-heatscreen.com/login i would like to take the existing user an create a new user/login with existing user in my application.

I have invested a ton of time in reading stackoverflow and django documentation, but cant puzzle things together....
Somehow is the best solution, to set a **remote_user** in django and solve the problem with django

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.RemoteUserMiddleware',
]
....
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.RemoteUserBackend',
]
```

Maybe you have some **hints/code snippeds/links** for me to point me to the right direction.
Would really appreciate any help. If you need some more information, i can post further information anytime.

Answer (score 0):

This Post was really helpful.

I created a Backend, where i get the user information via querystring und create/login the user.
With the middleware i managed to login automatically.

https://www.sipios.com/blog-tech/automatic-login-in-a-django-application-using-external-authentication